# Not run if value is not set in database

Tags: php

I have this code on my website. Basically it hides code on the site if you are not logged in.

In my database I have a table called "users" where userdata is stored. I have added a new column to the table called "subdomain" where the default value is 0 and 1 when it's active.

Except only being run when a user is logged in, I also only want the code to only be run if the column "subdomain" in the table "users" for the current logged in is set to 1. If it's not set to 1 the code should not be run and keep being hidden, even if the user is logged in.

How can this be done ?

Shows the username of the logged in user --> `<?php echo $Auth->username; ?>`

Show the user ID of the logged in user   --> `<?php echo $Auth->id; ?>`

There is no $Auth->subdomain. If i use id; ?> i get a user id like for example 1111 for the currently logged in user. Is it possible to make an if statement check the table called "user" for the same user ID Auth->id outputs and if it finds one, check if "subdomain" for hat user is set to 1 and if it is it runs the code ?

**CODE FROM THE SITE:**

```
<?php if (!$Auth->loggedIn()): ?>


<?php else: ?>  

//Code to be run
<div>
    <label for="shortUrlDomain"><?php echo t("short_url_domain", "Short Url Domain"); ?>:</label>
    <select id="shortUrlDomain" name="shortUrlDomain" style="width: 100%;">
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you using CakePHP?

Comment: not that i know of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to pull data from your database?
Assuming you also have `$Auth->subdomain` you could change the conditional to

```
 if (!$Auth->loggedIn() && $Auth->subdomain):
```

By the way you forgot to close your `<select>` tag and you haven't added any options

Comment: There is no $Auth->subdomain. If i use <?php echo $Auth->id; ?> i get a user id like for example 1111 for the currently logged in user. Is it possible to make an if statment check the table called "user" for the same user ID Auth->id outputs and if it finds one, check if "subdomain" for hat user is set to 1 and if it is it runs the code ?

Comment: Are you using any libraries? What are you using to query your database. If you have control over the code just add the subdomain column to your query

Comment: I think i found the right file, could you have a look? i looked trough it but i cant figure out what or where to do what to make $Auth->subdomain work in the way i want it to work.
https://pastebin.com/Tvh3hYx0

Comment: @Rizzzler this is a library / piece of borrowed code isn't it? I didn't test it but after taking a quick look adding the following lines at line 8, 22 and 188 should work `public $subdomain`, `$this->subdomain = null` and `$this->subdomain =  $row['subdomain'];` This will add a new public variable called subdomain and dump the `subdomain` column in it

Comment: Thank you! 
would the if statement you made above then be like this ? "" if (!$Auth->loggedIn() && $Auth->subdomain !== '1'): """ to make it work only if a user is logged in an subdomain is set to 1 ?

Comment: No it wouldn't. `!==` means 'is not equal to'. In order to make sure two values are identical you will need the `===` operator. If you want to account for type juggling use `==`. I urge you to take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php . Furthermore, make sure than when you're using `===` you're comparing variables of equal type (integer, string, boolean etc.). If `subdomain` is stored as an `int` comparing it to `'1'` will not work since that is of the type `string`.

Comment: I added the things you said in the file with the code as you can se in this new pastebin > https://pastebin.com/zZVFFb7U  i then tried to do a <?php echo $Auth->subdomain; ?> but nothing appears at all.

Comment: no error message at all the nothing show up on the page. if i change "subdomain" to "id" i get the users id showing up :/